# Most accessed files on filesystem in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, filesystems

I am looking for a way to keep track of most accessed files on a filesystem. I understand that setting `atime` or `lazytime` as a mount option might work. But, this doesn't seem to be an option in Kubernetes.

Also, even if this is set, it will only show that the file was accessed. Not the number of times the file was accessed.

Also, `auditd` is not an option since it doesn't work in a container.

Is there any other way to keep track of which file/s were accessed and how many times in a filesystem when running in K8s?

Comment: Since "auditd" is not an option, an alternative "Falco" from sysdig can be considered. You can check the below link for more information.
https://sysdig.com/blog/falco-vs-auditd-hids/

Comment: is the above comment useful in resolving the issue. Let me know if you need any additional help.

Comment: `falco` looks like a good option. I went ahead with using `fsnotify` as stated below. Since it allowed me to build locally and then package my app in a container and run it on K8s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option to do this seems to be to use https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify. It doesn't currently support getting notified when a file is read. But, it should be possible to hack fsnotify to make that happen, especially for Linux based systems.